# Understanding lifetimes: borrowed value does not live enough

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
    let long; 
    let str1="12345678".to_string();
    {
        let str2 = "123".to_string(); 
        long = longest(&str1, &str2);
    }
    println!("the longest string is: {}", long);
} 

fn longest<'a>(x:&'a str, y:&'a str) -> &'a str{
    if x.len() > y.len() {
        x
    } else {
        y
    }
}
```

gives

```
error[E0597]: `str2` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:6:31
  |
6 |         long = longest(&str1, &str2);
  |                               ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
7 |     }
  |     - `str2` dropped here while still borrowed
8 |     println!("the longest string is: {}", long);
  |                                           ---- borrow later used here
```

My theory is that, since the funtion `longest` has only one lifetime parameter, the compiler is making both `x` and `y` to have the lifetime of `str1`. So Rust is protecting me from calling `longest` and possibly receive back `str2` which has lifetime less than `str1` which is the chosen lifetime for `'a`.

Is my theory right?

Comment: That's exactly that.

Comment: @Yoric so the rule is to make `'a` be the lifetime parameter of the first parameter always?

Comment: By using the same `'a` for both `x` and `y` when you define `longest`, you specify that `'a` is the longest lifetime for which both `x` and  `y` are guaranteed to live. You're right to do so. If you had simply removed `'a` in your declaration, Rust would have basically inferred the same.

I'm not sure what you mean by "first parameter", though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at the signature for `longest`:

```rust
fn longest<'a>(x: &'a str, y: &'a str) -> &'a str
```

What this means is that for a given lifetime `'a`, **both arguments need to last at least for the length of that lifetime** (or longer, which doesn't really matter since you can safely shorten any lifetime in this case without any particular difference) and **the return value also lives as long as that lifetime**, because the return value **comes from one of the arguments** and therefore "inherits" the lifetime.

The sole reason for that is that at compile time, you can't really be sure whether `x` or `y` will be returned when compiling the function, so the compiler has to assume that either can be returned. Since you've bound both of them with the same lifetime (`x`, `y` and the return value have to live **at least** for the duration of `'a`), the resulting lifetime of `'a` is the smallest one. Now let's examine the usage of the function:

```rust
let long; 
let str1 = "12345678".to_string();
{
    let str2 = "123".to_string(); 
    long = longest(&str1, &str2);
}
```

You have two lifetimes here, the one outside the braces (the `main()` body lifetime) and the lifetime inside the braces (since everything between the braces is destroyed after the closing brace). Because you're storing the strings as `String` by using `.to_string()` (owned strings) rather than `&'static str` (borrowed string literals stored in the program executable file), **the string data gets destroyed as soon as it leaves the scope**, which, in the case of `str2`, is the brace scope. **The lifetime of `str2` ends before the lifetime of `str1`**, therefore, **the lifetime of the return value comes from `str2` rather than `str1`**.

You then try to store the return value into `long` — a variable outside the inner brace scope, i.e. **into a variable with a lifetime of the `main()` body rather than the scope**. But since the lifetime of `str2` restricts the lifetime of the return value for `longest` in this situation, **the return value of `longest` doesn't live after the braced scope** — the owned string you used to store `str2` is dropped at the end of the braced scope, releasing resources required to store it, i.e. from a memory safety standpoint it no longer exists.

If you try this, however, [everything works fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f47da73261115e6526ce893e825c537f):

```rust
let long; 
let str1 = "12345678";
{
    let str2 = "123"; 
    long = longest(str1, str2);
}
println!("the longest string is: {}", long);
```

But why? Remember what I said about how you stored the strings, more specifically, what I said about borrowed string literals which are stored in the executable file. These have a `'static` lifetime, which means the entire duration of the program's runtime existence. This means that `&'static` to anything (not just `str`) **always lives long enough**, since now you're referring to memory space inside the executable file (allocated at compile time) rather than a resource on the heap managed by `String` and dropped when the braced scope ends. You're no longer dealing with a managed resource, you're dealing with a resource **managed at compile time**, and that pleases the borrow checker by eliminating possible issues with its duration of life, since it's always `'static`.

Answer (score -2):

This code for the developer's perspective looks good and it should be because we are printing **long** in the outer scope so there should be no problem at all.

But Rust's compiler does a strict check on borrowed values and it needs to be sure that every value lives long enough for the variables that depend on that value.

> Compiler sees that **long** depends on the value whose lifetime is shorter that it's own i.e. **str**, it gives an error. Behind the scenes this is done by a borrow checker.

You can see more details about **borrow checker** [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#the-borrow-checker)